# Does the set of composable arrows in a category have to be a pullback?

Tags: ct.category-theory

> When defining a category, do we need to have the set of composable arrows be a pullback of the domain and codomain selecting functions? What can go wrong if we use a subobject of the pullback?

This arose when trying to formalize pasting diagrams with a minimal amount of graph theory; I would like to have a category whose objects are complex numbers and whose arrows are *injective* paths in the complex numbers (and constant paths for identities), to avoid things I don't need when drawing diagrams like loops or space filling curves.

The problem arises because domains and codomains are given by the image of $0$ and $1$ respectively, but composable arrows should have common domain/codomain *and not intersect* otherwise their composition wouldn't be an injective path and would fail to be in the category. (note that although pasting diagrams are not injective paths since they intersect at some vertices and thusly fail to be arrows in the injective path category, they are still diagrams in this category)

Comment: What would go wrong is simply that you would sometimes have a morphism f and a morphism g, the codomain of f would agree with domain of g, and yet your "generalized category" would not carry any data which specifies any kind of composite of f with g. Perhaps you could call this a "partial category," by analogy with "partial functions," "partial monoids," etc. A different approach, which fits into an existing body of theory in which there are already tools that might be useful to you, is to regard the structure as a 2-coskeletal simplicial set which happens to fail the weak Kan condition.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you for the suggestion; I am not well versed in simplical stuff, but I agree that using an approach with other tools available would be optimal.

Comment: The early chapters of E. Friedlander's book "Etale homotopy of simplicial schemes" present a nice treatment of simplicial objects and coskeleta, and I think that book's approach is a nice one for seeing how to fit your motivating example (which is not only a "partial category" but also has some geometric structure on the object set and the morphism set) into a simplicial framework.

Comment: @A.S. Much appreciated, I’ll see if the local university library has a copy (I can’t seem to find one not behind a paywall online), if not I’ll check scihub.

Comment: Peter Freyd had a notion of partial category.  Knowing him, he probably gave it a weird name, so I don't have a reference. However, it souds like you want to do homotopy theory in $\mathsf C$, which would definitely be somebody else's business, not categorists'.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thank you for the reference, I’ll see anything pops up in a google session. No desire to do homotopy theory, just need a sufficiently robust notion of ‘path’ in C to draw diagrams. The standard Moore path category works but has way too many paths in it and some ugly hypothesis are needed in the statement of some lemmas to restrict attention to paths we care about for drawing diagrams.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I think Freyd's notion is a [paracategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/paracategory).

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you, if you'd like to post that as an answer I'd accept. (if you have any comments to add about them I'd be glad to hear those too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are different possible notions of "partial category".  A definition due to Freyd is called a [paracategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/paracategory); this is an "unbiased" notion, equipped with partial $n$-ary composition operations for all $n\ge 0$ (although the case $n=0$ is required to be total, i.e. all identity arrows exist).  This can be reformulated in terms of generalized multicategories, as in the papers by Hermida and Mateus cited at the nLab page.

Another, more "biased" notion of "partial category" is a 2-coskeletal simplicial set with some, but not all, unique inner horn fillers.  Then the existence of a (necessarily unique) 2-simplex can be seen as a witness that a certain composite $g \circ f$ exists and equals $h$.  Again all identities exist, being given by the degeneracies (although one could imagine a semi-simplicial version that might not have all identities), and the composites are biased towards the binary, with the 3-simplices witnessing that associativity holds "whenever it makes sense".